# Authorization on spreadsheet script for own use

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a system (I'm the only user of this system, and that's not expected to change, ever) in which spreadsheets are copied from a template file. This template has a script, which populates a few menus to perform some operations. So each new copy of the template spreadsheet has its own copy of the script. The problem with this is that every time a new spreadsheet is used, the user (me) has to authorize the execution of the script. This didn't use to be that bad, but the authorization process has recently become way more annoying (see for example https://developers.google.com/apps-script/images/unverified-app-ui.gif). Given that I'm the only user of these spreadsheets, I think this process is unnecessary and wish to get around it.

I have tried to get around this by extracting the code into a standalone script file and publishing as an add on (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) but actually publishing it requires me to pay 5 dollars, and I think this is ridiculous given that I am the only user.

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for this kind of question.  It's a good question, it's just not a good Stack Overflow question.  It's better to ask the question at the Apps Script community:  [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Why is it not a good Stack Overflow question? I'm new at posting here.

Comment: A good question usually includes some code and details about error messages and/or what the expected results are versus what you are getting.  A good question is unique.  Your problem relates to a new authorization change in Apps Script.  You explained what you tried, but what you tried relates to **usage** not actual lines of code.  Your question is more of a customer service topic, or a complaint about a new procedure.  Stack Overflow is not Google's customer service or a place to file a complaint, or complain about what you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that's the intended behavior. Check [guide to the authorization lifecycle for add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle).

> - Add-on automatically runs its `onOpen(e)` function to add menu items when a document opens — but to protect users' data, Apps Script restricts what the `onOpen(e)` function can do.
> - Note that only published add-ons can be in `AuthMode.NONE`.
> - The concept of authorization modes applies to all Apps Script executions.